# about sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

this my query in sql:

```
with cte
as(
  select top 1 
    Id,
    (((DATEPART(hour, CAST([Time] AS DATETIME)) * 60) + (DATEPART(minute, CAST([Time] AS DATETIME)) ) )) AS Tim,
    Price
 from Prices order by [Time] desc
)
,cte1 as(
  select 
    (((DATEPART(hour, CAST([Time] AS DATETIME)) * 60) + (DATEPART(minute, CAST([Time] AS DATETIME)) ) )) as tim1
  from M1 
)
```

and now i want to do this ;if cte.tim=cte1.tim1 ,update a row in a table else insert into a table but i do not know how?
thanks alot

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If 2008 you might need `MERGE`

Answer (score 0):

You can only make the `SELECT` or the `UPDATE`, not both at the same time!

Check [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) for more info.